# Debugging function parameters' value in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm coming from scripting languages where this js possible, but I'm not sure if this is possible in C++. I'm working with an external module, and it uses a function, which parameters are not correct, so I tried to check them, but is not as simple as in JavaScript.

To check a parameter value, how can I do it? A simple cout gives me errors about types, and the same if I try to convert them to strings.

Is possible see the parameter value as in JS using a `console.log(fooParameter);` or something similar?

Thank's advanced!

Comment: If a data type doesn't have the output operator `<<` overloaded, then you can't use `cout` with it. You'd have to be able to call getter functions to get specific values about the type. There must be some kind of API to the external module that allows you to access information about the variables?

Comment: If you post a snippet of your code I'm sure someone will be happy to show you how to overload the << operator to be able to write your parameter to the console output

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use breakpoints in your IDE in order to pause the program when callstack reaches that point and see variables.

You can also overload the << operator in order to write to std::cout your parameter type if it's not a predefined one (string, int, etc).

Comment: I did it, but I want to know the value of the variable, not the type. And I think that's the problem because I can not print every type of variables as in script languages.

Comment: In debug mode you can see the variable type, and overloading << operator you can print it in the console.

Comment: Can i see the full variable or just the variable type?

Comment: You choose it. When you write the overloaded operator you can specify what you want to show and how. See [this](http://www.codersource.net/2010/02/14/overloading-stream-operators/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

c++ is an explicitly typed language, so you should have full control over what type is being passed.

However, you can print the variable type during runtime with:

```
#include <typeinfo>

// …
std::cout << typeid(fooParameter).name() << '\n';
```

Hope this helps!